# gpio.read null false while trying to read input

Tags: node.js, callback, null, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have been trying to read values from an ultrasonic sensor.
the code i am using

```
    //callbacks; got from a previous post
var gpio_read = function (channel) {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    gpio.read(channel, function (error, result) {
      console.log('gpio.read', error, result);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

//
var off = function () {
  gpio.write(trig, 0);
}
tank.getDistance = function () {
  var start, stop;
  gpio.write(trig, 0);
  gpio.write(trig, 1);
  setTimeout(off, 10);
  while (gpio_read(echo) === 0) {
    start = Date.now();
    console.log("nosig");
  }
  while (gpio_read(echo) === 1) {
    stop = Date.now();
    console.log("sig");
  }
  console.log(stop - start);
};

// pin setup
tank.initPins = function () {
  async.parallel([
    gpio.setup(p7, gpio.DIR_OUT),
    gpio.setup(p11, gpio.DIR_OUT),
    gpio.setup(p13, gpio.DIR_OUT),
    gpio.setup(p15, gpio.DIR_OUT),
    gpio.setup(echo, gpio.DIR_IN),
    gpio.setup(trig, gpio.DIR_OUT)
  ]);
};
```

i wrote similar python code and i get values back but here i get

```
gpio.read null false
gpio.read null true
```

I dont know why ?
I though it was due to busy pins so i tried resetting them before use and all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the gpio.read in a Promise.

```
   var gpio_read = function (channel) {
        gpio.read(channel, function (error, result) {
          console.log('gpio.read', error, result);
          return result;
      });
    }
```

The way you had it written (`new Promise(...)`) would just create a Promise but never actually return it to the calling function.  For that, you would need `return new Promise(...)` and to change the calling code to wait for the promise (eg `gpio_read.then(fn)`).

In the case of gpio.read it will already return a value once it is read from the board so you don't need to wrap it in a promise.